# How to make filter with two functions?

Tags: angularjs

I have two custom functions in controller:

```
$scope.isCategory = function(){
    return true;
}

$scope.isStatus = function(){
    return true;
}
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (projects | filter:isStatus) | orderBy : 'created_at'">
```

I  need to use both functions in filter at the same time. I tried this entry:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (projects | filter:isStatus;isCategory) | orderBy : 'created_at'">
```

It did not work

My secons filter does not work:

```
$scope.isCategory = function() {

            return function(item) {
                angular.forEach($scope.filterObj.categories, function(value) {
                     return $scope.inArray($scope.filterObj.categories, value);

                });

                return false;
            }   

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use multiple filters and call the function

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (projects | filter:isStatus() | filter: isCategory()) | orderBy : 'created_at'">
```

Edited

change the functions like this

```
  $scope.isStatus = function() {
    return function( item ) {
        console.log(item) 
        return item;
    };
  }
  $scope.isCategory = function(item){
     return function( item ) {
        console.log(item) 
        return item;
    };
  }
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/GXaNeBicrI2ii9kN4vKP?p=preview)

Comment: Does not work. In this case Angular JS can not find ` item.status` in: `$scope.isStatus = function(item) {
            
            return $scope.inArray($scope.filterObj.status, item.status);
        };`

Comment: I dont see console.log for second filter

Comment: @hAGARA forget to add return statements inside function. check the demo again